# jQuery, Get outerHTML of element, confusing output

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to re-code one of my older projects in jQuery using templating system. I've come to the point where i need to extract 'outerHTML' of an element. I found couple of solutions, but none seems to work properly for me.

The one I'm trying to get working now is

```
$(template).html($(element).clone().wrap('<p>').parent().html());
```

Where both `template` and `element` are strings, `template` holding entire template and `element` holding id of element im trying to get the outerHTML of.

What confuses me is this chained isntruction returns an Object where I expected it to return a string.

It would help me greatly if someone could explain me, what I'm doing wrong that I'm not getting a string. I'm strarting to be kind of frustrated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to get the html string from that code, you would need to modify it to:

```
var html = $(template).html($(element).clone().wrap('<p>').parent().html()).html();
```

When you pass a parameter to the html method you are setting the value, and for the purpose of being chainable jQuery will return the jQuery object when you set the property, which enables you to call additional methods in a row.  Something like:

```
$(template).html($(element).clone().wrap('<p>').parent().html()).width(500).height(200);
```

Does that make sense?